# Execution permission to all files created under a specific Directory by default

Tags: permissions, scripts, directory

I would like yo know if there is any method to provide execution permission to all files created under a **specific** directory by default.

i.e,

If I create a file say `foo.sh` under a directory `fooscripts`, it should have execution permission by default.
But if I create same file outside `fooscripts` it should be as usual.

Comment: Inotify is nice to use on a *specific* directory, not so much the other way around (exclude a specific dir). Is it importan for you that the files are not executable outside the directory?

Comment: @JacobVlijm no, outside the directory ---> let it be as usual (default permissions)

Comment: Ah, yes I should learn to read better :) Will post if I get home if not explained yet, or someone posted a brilliant solution in between :). I am on mobile now...

Comment: Hi Severus, posted my answer. Please mention if you manage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using inotifywait

As mentioned, you can use `inotify-tools` (`inotifywait`) to watch a specific directory for changes, for example by the script below, and subsequently set new files executable recursively.

The script uses the `inotifywait` -command, which is triggered by specific *events*, set by the `-e` -option. Luckily the command can be used in combination with multiple event types. 
Since you want the files inside the directory to be executable, in the script, two events are set:

```
-e move
```

which will notice files *moved* into the directory, and

```
-e create
```

which will notice new files *created* inside the directory.

Furthermore, the options:

```
-m -r
```

are to make the command run indefinitely ("monitor") and recursively in the directory, while:

```
--format '%w%f'
```

outputs the directory (path to the file, `%w`) plus the filename (`%f`) that caused the event.

More on options of `inotifywait` can be found [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait), or, as always, in `man inotifywait`

#### The script

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# you might want to change the directory below into the targeted directory
DIR="/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test123"
inotifywait -m -r -e move -e create --format '%w%f' "$DIR" | while read f

do
  chmod +x "$f"
done
```

#### How to use

1. You will probably have to install `inotify-tools` first:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install inotify-tools
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `set_executable.sh`
3. In the head of the script, set the path to the targeted folder:

   ```bsh
   # change the directory below into the targeted directory
   DIR="/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test123"
   ```

   ...and test-run the script from a terminal.
4. If all works fine, add the script to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add.

#### Note

Note that `notifywait` acts on *changes* (events). That implies that files that were added or created *before* the script ran will not be effected. Nor will it re- set the files executable if you manually and deliberately set them *not* to be executable, while they are inside the targeted directory.

Comment: Works perfectly as expected     , learned sth new.

Answer (score 1):

No. You could use `inotify` to watch the directory and `chmod` new files.

Here is how to find out about `inotify`:

```
man -k inotify
for i in $( man -k inotify | awk '{ print $1 }' ) ; do 
    man $i 
    read -p "Print?: " ans 
    if [[ "x$ans" = "xy" ]] ; then 
        man -t $i | lpr -J $i 
    fi 
done
# sr is from surfraw, Shell Users Revoultionary Front Rage Against the Web
sr google inotify
```

Comment: could you please tell me how to use `inotify`?

Comment: Thanks  , This is informative , working as expected but getting this error each time : `lpr: Error - no default destination available`.  [here is my output (screen shot)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0JB0X.png)

Comment: That's a new question - ask it in a new question.