# How do I run a python script whenever a file is created in a directory?

Tags: scripts, python, directory, automation, inotify

So, I'm trying to do this, somewhat, simple task, but I have not been successful yet. I'm hoping that changes now.

### The goal:

Run `/var/www/lager-scanner/filer/pluk_script.py` whenever there is a new file in `/var/www/lager-scanner/filer/Nav/FromNav`, and run this as the `www-data` user.

Is there someone out there how can tell me how to do that?

All the folders in `/var/www` are owned by the `www-data` user and group and have `775` permissions.

Comment: Would you consider using inotify? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inotify

Comment: Yup, but I don't know how to get it going, couldn't find a guide that was detailed enough, for me to follow it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/546264/158442

Comment: Hi Folkmann, did you notice the answer(s)?

Comment: Yes, I just havn't had the time to try them and reply.

Comment: Hi @Folkmann could you indicate when you could try the answer(s)? I'd prefer not to leave the question in an open state.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm pretty tied up atm, so I properbly won't be able to try is before the 20th or 21st of June

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a dupe, but in the accepted answer on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781799/execution-permission-to-all-files-created-under-a-specific-directory-by-default/781909#781909), it is explained how to run a script (or any command) whenever a file is added or created in an arbitrary directory. In your case, the only needed event- trigger is:

```
-e create
```

Furthermore, since you are not using the path to the file as an argument, you can skip the `--format` -section.

The script to run in the background then simply is:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/var/www/lager-scanner/filer/Nav/FromNav"
inotifywait -m -r -e create "$DIR" | while read f

do
    # you may want to release the monkey after the test :)
    echo monkey
    # <whatever_command_or_script_you_liketorun>
done
```

#### Explanation

As explained in the linked question:

```
-e create
```

will notice new files *created* inside the directory.

The options:

```
-m -r
```

are to make the command run indefinitely ("monitor") and recursively in the directory.

According to [this](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2008/01/04/why-you-should-not-use-pyinotify/), using `pyinotify` is not the best option.

### EDIT

In a comment you mention it does not work, *and* you mention the targeted folder is remote. Although not exactly the same, the issue seems related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4231277/1391444): 
*the change is not visible to the kernel; it happens entirely remotely.*

A (tested) work around is to mount the remote folder locally.

Comment: So I finally had time to try this :) I looked at the linked question and followed, but it doesn't work :/ It just outputs `Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.` and stays like that. Any idea what I did wrong? It doesn't even echo monkey :/

Comment: I am in a conference, hope to be home before midnight :) Silly question, but you tested to add a file ?

Comment: Jup :) Still nothing

Comment: @Folkmann wait, did you *move* a file or create one? There is practically no option it wouldn't work.

Comment: I created one. The folder it is watching is a Samba Shared folder.

Comment: Hi @Folkmann updated my answer.

Comment: Oh well :/ I guess I'll just create a cronjob that runs as often as I can got it to :) Thanks for trying, guess I should have mentioned it was a remote folder mounted as a subfolder, that was being watched :/

Comment: I had to install `inotify-tools` for it to work

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trimmed down version of the example from the inotify page on PyPI 
(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inotify) to get you started:

```
import inotify.adapters
import os

notifier = inotify.adapters.Inotify()
notifier.add_watch('/home/student')

for event in notifier.event_gen():
    if event is not None:
        # print event      # uncomment to see all events generated
        if 'IN_CREATE' in event[1]:
             print "file '{0}' created in '{1}'".format(event[3], event[2])
             os.system("your_python_script_here.py")
```

It creates a Inotify object then adds a directory to watch using the add_watch() method.  Next it creates a event generator from the Inotify object using the event_gen() method.  Finally it iterate overs that generator

Now file operations that affect the watched directory will generate one or more events.  Each event takes the form of a tuple with four values:

- An _INOTIFY_EVENT tuple (omitted in the output below for clarity)
- A list of strings describing the events
- The name of the directory affected
- The name of the file affected

Running the above example with the first print statement uncommented and then creating the file 'new' in the watched directory gives this output:

```
( (...), ['IN_CREATE'], '/home/student', 'new')    
file 'new' created in '/home/student'
( (...), ['IN_ISDIR', 'IN_OPEN'], '/home/student', '')
( (...), ['IN_ISDIR', 'IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE'/home/student', '')
( (...), ['IN_OPEN'], '/home/student', 'new')
( (...), ['IN_ATTRIB'], '/home/student', 'new')
( (...), ['IN_CLOSE_WRITE'], '/home/student', 'new')
```

Since the 'IN_CREATE' event occurs when a new file is created, this is where you would add whatever code you wanted to run.

Comment: `os.system` is really, really old fashioned, outdated and should not be used anymore.